# How to return some data from HttpServlet's doPost() method?

Tags: java, servlets, http-post

I am writing a java class that extends HttpServlet thus overwrites doPost() method. Inside the doPost() method, some data object is assembled, but I am not sure what is a better way to return the data. For instance,

```
public class FormSubmission extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // http request is parsed to assemble an object, e.g., a List
        List L = parseRequest(request);

        // Question: how to return List L for use by Server?         
    }
}
```

One way I can think of is to declare a static variable as

```
Public static List L;
```

and call `FormSubmission.L`, which basically makes List L a global variable.

Another way is to write data bytes to a file so that it can be read back into a List later.

But is there better way to handle such situation?

***Use cases based on Comment:***

Two forms with HTTP/POST are created in main page "index.html", Form A and B. It is required that a user submits Form A first, and then submits Form B. Submitting Form A triggers the above ***doPost()*** method, such that ***List L*** is constructed. The scenario is to how to make this List available to process Form B submission. Specifically, how to have Form B's ***doPost()*** method be able to access ***List L*** created from A during the previous stage.

Comment: What is your use case? Which classes would use the list? A business service or a JSP for display purposes?

Comment: Basically, I created two forms, Form A and B. If I submit Form A, the above doPost() method will be called and List L is constructed. Then if I click to submit Form B, the objective is that Form B's doPost() method is able to pull in the List L created from Form A. So my trouble is how to pass the value from A's doPost() for B to use.

Comment: Are the forms submitting to the same FormSubmission servlet?

Comment: no, they are going to two different servlet classes, each having their own doPost() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `FormASubmission` servlet, save the `List` to the user's `session` object.

```
List L = parseRequest(request);

HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("FormADataList", L);
```

Then in your `FormBSumission` servlet, you can retrieve this `List` as

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
List L = (List) session.getAttribute("FormADataList");
```

---

`HttpSession` is an *interface* whose underlying implementation is provided by the container. This *scoped* object is created only once per user/browser interacting with the application. Any user data stored here remains available for the length of the *session* across multiple HTTP requests from the same user.

The [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)'s javadoc says it

> Provides a way to identify a user across more than one page request or visit to a Web site and to store information about that user.

Comment: So a HttpSession is shared across different servlets - that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: Correct. I added some more details on that. Also note that `session.getAttribute()` returns an `Object`; so, it needs *type casting* before use.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using Session scope and put there.
You can reach object from that session.

```
final HttpSession session = req.getSession();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do a  RequestDispatcher

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("name.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
```